# Trouble with Rails Version 4.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, I'm trying to follow along with Rails in Action 4 book.

Am currently on chapter 3

This is what the Gemfile is supposed to be:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.12"
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', "2.0.2"
end
```

It's the first time I'm dealing with rails 4 and ruby 2.

When I tried to run `bundle update`, I get this:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

The rails version I do have is this: `Rails 4.0.0.rc1`

And if you look at this page: http://rubygems.org/gems/rails, they don't seem to have Rails 4.0.0

I'm at loss how to resolve this situation.

And every time I try to change the `gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1`, I get this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
In Gemfile:
sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby

rails (= 4.0.0.rc1) ruby depends on
  sprockets-rails (2.0.0.rc4)
```

Now the weirdest thing is that my laptop is now saying it dosen't have rails! Everytime I try to run for the version of it, it says:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

But I didn't do anything to RVM or change rails, or whatever else!

Am utterly baffled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a pre-release version of the book, which is written in anticipation of what the gem versions will be once the book launches. Try this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.0.0.rc4'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.rc1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.12"
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', "2.0.2"
end
```

Comment: But, um, do you have any idea why now, when even though it installed Rails 4 fine via bundle update, whenever I try "rails -v", I get this: "Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type: $ sudo gem install rails" even though if I open a new terminal window, it shows the version just fine?

Comment: try `bundle install --binstubs`

Comment: and/or you may need to update rubygems -- `gem update --system`

Comment: or try "bundle exec rails -v" and if you're using RVM, check that it is loaded and which ruby version and gempack is active.